# Почему размер hashmap уменьшается в Java

Tags: java, hashmap

```
HashMap<String, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>(4, 0.75f);
System.out.println(hashMap.size()); // 0
hashMap.put("a", 1);
System.out.println(hashMap.size()); // 1
hashMap.remove("a");
System.out.println(hashMap.size()); // 0
```

OpenJDK 14.0.1
Почему при создании мапы с указанным начальным размером 4, размер ее равен 0?
И почему при удалении элемента размер мапы уменьшается? Это какое-то нововведение в какой-то Jav`e? И вообще по умолчанию размер должен же быть равен 16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно различать вместимость (`capacity`) и размер (`size`).

Значение 4 указываемое в конструкторе, это не размер таблицы, а вместимость, т.е. количество памяти заранее выделенное под хранение элементов.

`size` же возвращает, количество элементов, которые хранится в конкретный момент времени.

Answer (score 0):

У `HashMap` есть поле `threshold` — предельное количество элементов, при достижении которого размер хэш-таблицы увеличивается вдвое. Рассчитывается по формуле `(capacity * loadFactor)`

`loadFactor` — этот параметр отвечает за то, при какой степени загруженности текущей хеш-таблицы необходимо создавать новую хеш-таблицу, т.е. как только хеш-таблица заполнилась на 75%, будет создана новая хеш-таблица с перемещением в неё текущих элементов (затратная операция, так как требуется перехеширование всех элементов);

Т.е. при инициализации размер остается равным 0 и увеличивается только при добавлении новых элементов.